# How do I change the class to public?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, public

How do I change the class to public and eliminate this message?

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
This class should be public (android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.HomeView) BootleJFL       line 1  Android Lint Problem
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that gets this warning?

Answer (score 3):

That would be an [Android Lint Checks](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks)

#### Instantiatable

> Summary: Ensures that classes registered in the manifest file are instantiatable
>
> - Priority: 6 / 10
> - Severity: Warning
> - Category: Correctness
>
> Activities, services, broadcast receivers etc. registered in the manifest file
>   must be "instiantable" by the system, which means that the class must be
>   public, it must have an empty public constructor, and if it's an inner class,
>   it must be a static inner class.

Make sure its setting is set to Warning (or to Ignore) for your `v7-appcompat` library.

Comment: what if i don't have appCompat library at all?

Comment: Not sure, that would be better addressed as a separate question

Answer (score 0):

You can restart Eclipse and it will be fine. Or you may try to Go to Window->Preferences->Android Now find your SDK location (most likely: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows). Click apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse:

`Project > Clean > OK`
Or Try:

`Preferences -> Android Lint Preferences`
Search for `Instantiatable` and set as `Warning`.

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html

This worked for me.